# How do I add certain Fields to a View (not all fields are showing in Add list)?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I'm creating a view where I'd like to output a custom field. I am basing this off an already existing view, which already uses the said custom field.

However, when I hit the 'Add' button in the View's Fields section I do not see the same Fields as the already-built view.

Is there some way to associate the View with a certain group of Fields so that I can add them?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to associate the View with a certain group of Fields

Yes, this is done by adding a **relationship**.

For example, if you create a content view and add a relationship of `Content: Author`, you will now be able to add user fields, such as `User: Picture` or `User: E-mail` to name a few.

Therefore, look if the already built in view is using a relationship. (It's under Advanced, located on the far right of the View's settings).

[image]